# Как испрaвить бaг?

Tags: slick.js

пользователь заходит на страницу, бесконечный слайдер с меняющими слайдами.
Только после того как навели курсор на картинку - уменьшается скорость движения слайдов. Увели курсор - должна быть стандартная скорость ( которая по загрузке страницы)

Cейчас - даже если пользователь не навел курсор на картинку - то через некоторое время слайдер останавливается и запускается

https://jsbin.com/dojetugali/edit?html,output